# Openlayers 3 styling point features with icons

Tags: openlayers

I'm using the following code which defines a default style, that is used to style point (and other) features in OpenLayers 3.
When I use the var image to style my features everything is Ok, and the points are rendered on my map. When I try to use var icon with the same dataset instead, nothing is displayed. In my browsers devtools I see, that the icon is loaded?

Any ideas? where the mistake lies?

```
//
// -------- Defining default style settings ----------
//
 var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
   color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
 });
 var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: '#3399CC',
   width: 1.25
 });

 var image = new ol.style.Circle({
       fill: fill,
       stroke: stroke,
       radius: 5
 });

 var icon = new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
          size: [52, 52],
          offset: [52, 0],
          opacity: 0.5,
          scale: 1.0,
          src: "./img/mmOrange.png"
 });

 var style = new ol.style.Style({
     image: image,  // this works, but when I use image: icon, nothing is displayed
     fill: fill,
     stroke: stroke
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to make sure the src of image is right: just try
ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png'
  }));
to see if something displays.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it also with the new source. I can see in Firefox-dev-tools, that the icon is loaded, but it does not show up on the map? I reduced my code to the absolute minimum, but I don't get icons displayed. When using the image style everything works fine. I've tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. ???

Comment: Have you tried ol.style.Style without parameters 'fill/stroke' ?:   var style = new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Icon ({
     src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png' 
     });
   });

Comment: Yes I did, see the code below.

Comment: In your code below, why you add offset: [52, 0] ? while the size of icon.png is only 32x48 pixel. Using just 'src' as parameter.

Comment: Oh, You're right! I should have read the documentation better to understand the consequences of anchor, size and offset. After all it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For me 'color' did the trick

```
style: new Style({
    image: new Icon({
            color: 'white',
            scale: 0.2,
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            src: 'assets/img/'+ layerName +'.svg'
          })
    })
```